# Angular - Input with ngx-mask MatDatepicker and reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker, ngx-mask

I would like to add a reactive form control over a form and an error is triggered:

> More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

Everything works separately, reactive form validation, mask or matDatepicker, any couple combination also works, but the three together prompt the error.

Here is my code:

In component.ts

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl()
  });
```

In component.html

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput [matDatepicker]="date_picker" mask="d0/M0/0000" formControlName="date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date_picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #date_picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I'm using:

```
"@angular/cli": "8.3.19"
"ngx-mask": "8.1.7"
"@angular/material": "8.2.3"
```

Comment: Here is a StackBlitz of my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcmk8w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling the same issue.
According to this thread, there is no solution only a workaround:
[Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/issues/50)

I used the workaround mentioned, with vanilla-text-mask as a temporary (I hope) solution, but there is no activity on the above thread so...
Here is the link to the workaround:
[Use more than one CustomValueAcessor in one Input field](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16755)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you point out the most importent content of the second link (the part that helped you)?

Comment: I wrote a similar directive with minor changes I needed for my code: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16755#issuecomment-365045055

Then, if you scroll a bit down, there is a bug that came up for me too (the extra character at the end). The sample code in this answer fixed it: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16755#issuecomment-375330165

I know it is  a bit hacky but this is the best solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1 - Create an auxiliar masked input below the date input, binding it's value to the date input using NgModel. (Don't use matInput directive on the masked input!)

```
 <input #dateInput matInput formControlName="control"  [matDatepicker]="picker" etc.../>
 <input #maskedInput [(ngModel)]="dateInput.value" mask="00/00/0000" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false" etc.../>
```

2 - Hide the date input using css:

```
input:first-child {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

3 - Relay focus events from the date input to the masked input

```
<input #dateInput (focus)="maskedInput.focus()" etc...>
<input #maskedInput etc...>
```

4 - Relay input events from the masked input to the date input

```
<input #dateInput etc.../>
<input #maskedInput (input)="dispatch(dateInput)" etc.../>
```

5 - Create a 'dispatch' function in component ts

```
dispatch(input: HTMLInputElement){
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

Working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gyy1i4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts